# Office 2016 installed but errors on run

Tags: wine, 32-bit

I have a Win10 laptop running Oracle VM running Ubuntu 20.04.01 LTS upgraded to the latest and greatest. I went thru the instructions, and installed wine & POL and office 2016 would not install. So I used wine 5.4 and the install went thru with a final error (did not log) in the end. I still saw the application installed and I created the desktop icons using the steps given thru POL.

But when I try to launch Word or excel, it errors out with an unhandled exception. Pasting my log below. Any help will be appreciated.

```
Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x00000000 in 32-bit code (0x00000000).
Register dump:
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:0063 GS:006b
 EIP:00000000 ESP:1d90fbec EBP:1d90fc48 EFLAGS:00210212(  R- --  I   -A- - )
 EAX:00000303 EBX:030b1820 ECX:00000001 EDX:0309ed38
 ESI:00000000 EDI:0308ea4c
Stack dump:
0x1d90fbec:  f75b461b 00000000 00000001 00000303
0x1d90fbfc:  00000001 00000303 030b1820 1d90fc48
0x1d90fc0c:  f75b4606 00008c8e 00000001 0309ed38
0x1d90fc1c:  00000006 030b0df0 00000303 00000001
0x1d90fc2c:  1d5f704c 00000b20 00000007 f5bc513d
0x1d90fc3c:  0000001c 030b0df0 80000000 1d90feb8
Backtrace:
=>0 0x00000000 (0x1d90fc48)
  1 0xf75417e0 draw_primitive+0x8df() in wined3d (0x1d90feb8)
  2 0xf7548195 wined3d_cs_exec_draw+0x104() in wined3d (0x1d90fef8)
  3 0xf7549f22 wined3d_cs_run+0xc1() in wined3d (0x1d90ff48)
  4 0x7bcc9ddc call_thread_func_wrapper+0xb() in ntdll (0x1d90ff5c)
  5 0x7bcce949 call_thread_func+0x88() in ntdll (0x1d90ffdc)
  6 0x7bcc9dce call_thread_entry+0x9() in ntdll (0x1d90ffec)
0x00000000: -- no code accessible --
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (211 modules)
PE    340000-  35d000   Deferred        outlookservicing
PE    360000-  363000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0
PE    3b0000-  3dd000   Deferred        d3d10_1
PE    400000- 215f000   Deferred        outlook
PE   2160000- 2352000   Deferred        c2r32
PE   27a0000- 2a9d000   Deferred        comctl32
PE   7740000- 7dd1000   Deferred        olmapi32
PE   b670000- b877000   Deferred        urlmon
PE   b880000- b8f6000   Deferred        wintrust
PE   bb30000- bd5c000   Deferred        d3d11
PE   d150000- db94000   Deferred        outllibr
PE   e2c0000- e3a8000   Deferred        webservices
PE   e3e0000- e420000   Deferred        jsproxy
PE   e450000- e51b000   Deferred        msoaria
PE   f450000- f69d000   Deferred        riched20
PE   f6a0000- f957000   Deferred        mapir
PE  10000000-101ea000   Deferred        appvisvsubsystems32
PE  17990000-19c43000   Deferred        wwlib
PE  19c50000-1a8b4000   Deferred        oart
PE  1b930000-1b95a000   Deferred        contab32
PE  58800000-58946000   Deferred        msxml6
PE  61740000-61743000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0
PE  61f00000-61f32000   Deferred        sxs
PE  62140000-62159000   Deferred        wtsapi32
PE  62180000-62190000   Deferred        normaliz
PE  622c0000-622c3000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0
PE  62340000-623a6000   Deferred        uxtheme
PE  62780000-627a3000   Deferred        mspatcha
PE  62800000-6289a000   Deferred        usp10
PE  62940000-62966000   Deferred        imagehlp
PE  62e40000-62e45000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-multibyte-l1-1-0
PE  63340000-63344000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0
PE  63a00000-63a03000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0
PE  63ac0000-63ad9000   Deferred        dwmapi
PE  64000000-6400d000   Deferred        api-ms-win-shcore-scaling-l1-1-1
PE  643c0000-6447e000   Deferred        mscoree
PE  64540000-645f8000   Deferred        winhttp
PE  64700000-6473c000   Deferred        concrt140
PE  64b40000-64b71000   Deferred        shcore
PE  65200000-655f9000   Deferred        ole32
PE  65980000-65997000   Deferred        version
PE  66700000-6676d000   Deferred        rsaenh
PE  66c80000-66cef000   Deferred        msvcp140
PE  67940000-67a2f000   Deferred        wbemprox
PE  67f00000-67f1d000   Deferred        userenv
PE  68340000-68431000   Deferred        msctf
PE  68ac0000-68ada000   Deferred        powrprof
PE  68c40000-68d2b000   Deferred        shlwapi
PE  69580000-69584000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0
PE  69b00000-69c21000   Deferred        d3dcompiler_47
PE  69d80000-69d83000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0
PE  69ec0000-69ef9000   Deferred        netprofm
PE  6a080000-6a097000   Deferred        wevtapi
PE  6a300000-6a5d0000   Deferred        oleaut32
PE  6a6c0000-6a6c3000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0
PE  6a900000-6aa44000   Deferred        setupapi
PE  6b4c0000-6b60c000   Deferred        wininet
PE  6ba80000-6ba8c000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-fibers-l1-1-1
PE  6be90000-6bebd000   Deferred        osppc
PE  6bf00000-6bf19000   Deferred        schannel
PE  6c0c0000-6c0f2000   Deferred        imm32
PE  6c9c0000-6cab3000   Deferred        d3d10
PE  6d780000-6d784000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0
PE  6d7c0000-6d814000   Deferred        xmllite
PE  6d880000-6db39000   Deferred        d2d1
PE  6dbc0000-6dc01000   Deferred        mpr
PE  6df80000-6df84000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0
PE  6e1c0000-6e204000   Deferred        cabinet
PE  6e480000-6e497000   Deferred        ncrypt
PE  6e4c0000-6e4ec000   Deferred        d3d10core
PE  6e540000-6e54d000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0
PE  6e8c0000-6e8cd000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-1
PE  6ecc0000-6ecd3000   Deferred        vcruntime140
PE  6f280000-6f2ad000   Deferred        odbccp32
PE  6f680000-6f843000   Deferred        gdiplus
PE  6fdc0000-6ff4a000   Deferred        rpcrt4
PE  70700000-70714000   Deferred        rstrtmgr
PE  70780000-70785000   Deferred        api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0
PE  70c00000-70c14000   Deferred        dhcpcsvc
PE  71400000-71867000   Deferred        msi
ELF 7a800000-7a94c000   Deferred        opengl32<elf>
  \-PE  7a840000-7a94c000   \               opengl32
PE  7b000000-7b20e000   Deferred        kernelbase
ELF 7b400000-7b678000   Deferred        kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b420000-7b678000   \               kernel32
ELF 7bc00000-7bd5f000   Dwarf           ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc30000-7bd5f000   \               ntdll
ELF 7c000000-7c004000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
ELF 7cb4e000-7cba4000   Deferred        libgssapi_krb5.so.2
ELF 7cba4000-7cbaa000   Deferred        libkeyutils.so.1
ELF 7cbaa000-7cbb9000   Deferred        libkrb5support.so.0
ELF 7cbb9000-7cbbf000   Deferred        libcom_err.so.2
ELF 7cbbf000-7cbf3000   Deferred        libk5crypto.so.3
ELF 7cbf3000-7ccd4000   Deferred        libkrb5.so.3
ELF 7ccd4000-7ccf1000   Deferred        kerberos<elf>
  \-PE  7cce0000-7ccf1000   \               kerberos
ELF 7cdf1000-7cdfb000   Deferred        libffi.so.7
ELF 7cdfb000-7ce8b000   Deferred        libgmp.so.10
ELF 7ce8b000-7cec4000   Deferred        libhogweed.so.5
ELF 7cec4000-7cf04000   Deferred        libnettle.so.7
ELF 7cf04000-7cf1b000   Deferred        libtasn1.so.6
ELF 7cf1b000-7d09d000   Deferred        libunistring.so.2
ELF 7d09d000-7d0bd000   Deferred        libidn2.so.0
ELF 7d0bd000-7d215000   Deferred        libp11-kit.so.0
ELF 7d215000-7d415000   Deferred        libgnutls.so.30
ELF 7d42e000-7d478000   Deferred        secur32<elf>
  \-PE  7d440000-7d478000   \               secur32
ELF 7d4a7000-7decb000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  7d4e0000-7decb000   \               shell32
ELF 7df61000-7df6b000   Deferred        libuuid.so.1
ELF 7df6b000-7df97000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7df97000-7dfe5000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7dfe5000-7e003000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7e003000-7e042000   Deferred        libpng16.so.16
ELF 7e042000-7e108000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7e108000-7e243000   Deferred        msvcr120<elf>
  \-PE  7e140000-7e243000   \               msvcr120
ELF 7e243000-7e38b000   Deferred        ucrtbase<elf>
  \-PE  7e280000-7e38b000   \               ucrtbase
ELF 7e38b000-7e3b3000   Deferred        dnsapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e390000-7e3b3000   \               dnsapi
ELF 7e3b3000-7e3f1000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
  \-PE  7e3c0000-7e3f1000   \               ws2_32
ELF 7e3f1000-7e40a000   Deferred        libresolv.so.2
ELF 7e40a000-7e43b000   Deferred        iphlpapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e410000-7e43b000   \               iphlpapi
ELF 7e43b000-7e486000   Deferred        netapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e450000-7e486000   \               netapi32
ELF 7e486000-7e6f6000   Deferred        user32<elf>
  \-PE  7e4c0000-7e6f6000   \               user32
ELF 7e6f6000-7e7ec000   Deferred        msvcrt<elf>
  \-PE  7e720000-7e7ec000   \               msvcrt
ELF 7e7ec000-7e975000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e810000-7e975000   \               gdi32
ELF 7e975000-7e9ff000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e990000-7e9ff000   \               advapi32
ELF 7eecd000-7eee2000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7eee2000-7efe7000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF eb41d000-eb500000   Deferred        libgcrypt.so.20
ELF eb843000-eb8fe000   Deferred        libsystemd.so.0
ELF ec4a1000-ec4ff000   Deferred        libdbus-1.so.3
ELF ed510000-ed536000   Deferred        libgpg-error.so.0
ELF ed536000-ed559000   Deferred        liblz4.so.1
ELF ed559000-ed5fd000   Deferred        libcups.so.2
ELF ef115000-ef141000   Deferred        liblzma.so.5
ELF ef141000-ef157000   Deferred        libavahi-client.so.3
ELF ef170000-ef1ff000   Deferred        dwrite<elf>
  \-PE  ef180000-ef1ff000   \               dwrite
ELF efb00000-efb0f000   Deferred        libavahi-common.so.3
ELF efb0f000-efb65000   Deferred        winspool<elf>
  \-PE  efb20000-efb65000   \               winspool
ELF efb65000-efbff000   Deferred        dbghelp<elf>
  \-PE  efb80000-efbff000   \               dbghelp
ELF f0501000-f0509000   Deferred        libnss_dns.so.2
ELF f150b000-f1534000   Deferred        libtinfo.so.6
ELF f1534000-f153f000   Deferred        librt.so.1
ELF f153f000-f1577000   Deferred        libedit.so.2
ELF f1577000-f1582000   Deferred        libatomic.so.1
ELF f1582000-f15a1000   Deferred        libgcc_s.so.1
ELF f177f000-f17dc000   Deferred        libvulkan.so.1
ELF f17dc000-f17e6000   Deferred        libdrm_nouveau.so.2
ELF f17e6000-f17f3000   Deferred        libdrm_amdgpu.so.1
ELF f17f3000-f1811000   Deferred        libelf.so.1
ELF f1811000-f1821000   Deferred        libdrm_radeon.so.1
ELF f1821000-f1833000   Deferred        libsensors.so.5
ELF f1833000-f18da000   Deferred        libzstd.so.1
ELF f18da000-f5aab000   Deferred        libllvm-10.so.1
ELF f5aab000-f7271000   Deferred        swrast_dri.so
ELF f7271000-f7274000   Deferred        libxshmfence.so.1
ELF f7274000-f727d000   Deferred        libxcb-sync.so.1
ELF f727d000-f7282000   Deferred        libxcb-present.so.0
ELF f7282000-f7288000   Deferred        libxcb-dri3.so.0
ELF f7288000-f728d000   Deferred        libxdamage.so.1
ELF f728d000-f7294000   Deferred        libxcb-dri2.so.0
ELF f7294000-f7299000   Deferred        libx11-xcb.so.1
ELF f7299000-f72b8000   Deferred        libxcb-glx.so.0
ELF f72b8000-f72ce000   Deferred        libdrm.so.2
ELF f72ce000-f72f7000   Deferred        libglapi.so.0
ELF f72f7000-f7377000   Deferred        libglx_mesa.so.0
ELF f7377000-f73b3000   Deferred        libglx.so.0
ELF f73b3000-f7430000   Deferred        libgldispatch.so.0
ELF f7430000-f749d000   Deferred        libgl.so.1
ELF f749d000-f7670000   Dwarf           wined3d<elf>
  \-PE  f74f0000-f7670000   \               wined3d
ELF f7670000-f76b4000   Deferred        dxgi<elf>
  \-PE  f7680000-f76b4000   \               dxgi
ELF f76b4000-f76db000   Deferred        bcrypt<elf>
  \-PE  f76c0000-f76db000   \               bcrypt
ELF f76db000-f77ef000   Deferred        crypt32<elf>
  \-PE  f7700000-f77ef000   \               crypt32
ELF f7835000-f783d000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF f783d000-f784a000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF f784a000-f785f000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF f785f000-f7864000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF f7864000-f7873000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF f7873000-f787f000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF f787f000-f7887000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF f7887000-f788c000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF f788c000-f78ab000   Deferred        libbsd.so.0
ELF f78ab000-f78da000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF f78da000-f7a29000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF f7a29000-f7a40000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF f7a59000-f7b20000   Deferred        winex11<elf>
  \-PE  f7a80000-f7b20000   \               winex11
ELF f7b24000-f7b2a000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF f7b2a000-f7d18000   Deferred        libc.so.6
ELF f7d18000-f7d3b000   Deferred        libpthread.so.0
ELF f7d42000-f7d4a000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF f7d4a000-f7d50000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF f7d54000-f7edf000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF f7ee1000-f7f0e000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
00000008 (D) C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE
    0000008e    0
    0000008b    0 <==
    0000008a    0
    00000089    0
    00000088    0
    0000006f    0
    0000006c    1
    00000068    0
    00000058    0
    00000057    0
    00000055    0
    00000054    0
    00000053    0
    00000052    0
    00000051    0
    00000050    0
    0000004f    0
    0000004e    0
    00000009    0
0000000e services.exe
    00000077    0
    00000071    0
    00000060    0
    0000005d    0
    00000059    0
    0000002c    0
    00000021    0
    0000001c    0
    00000018    0
    00000013    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000011 winedevice.exe
    00000019    0
    00000017    0
    00000016    0
    00000012    0
0000001a plugplay.exe
    0000001e    0
    0000001d    0
    0000001b    0
0000001f winedevice.exe
    00000025    0
    00000024    0
    00000023    0
    00000022    0
    00000020    0
00000026 OfficeClickToRun.exe
    0000004d    0
    00000044    0
    00000042    0
    00000041    0
    00000040    0
    0000003f    0
    0000003d    0
    0000003c    0
    00000039    0
    00000037    0
    00000036    0
    00000034    0
    00000030    0
    0000002f    0
    0000002e    0
    0000002d    0
    0000002b    0
    0000002a    0
    00000029    0
    00000028    0
    00000027    0
00000048 explorer.exe
    0000004c    0
    0000004b    0
    0000004a    0
    00000049    0
0000005e OSPPSVC.EXE
    00000086    0
    0000006b    0
    00000069    0
    00000067    0
    00000064    0
    00000063    0
    00000061    0
    0000005f    0
0000006d svchost.exe
    00000083    0
    00000081    0
    00000080    0
    00000074    0
    00000073    0
    00000072    0
    0000006e    0
00000075 rpcss.exe
    0000007b    0
    0000007a    0
    00000079    0
    00000078    0
    00000076    0
System information:
    Wine build: wine-5.4
    Platform: i386
    Version: Windows 7
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 5.4.0-48-generic
```

Thanks

Rahul

Comment: Did I misunderstand: Your "bare metal" operating system is Windows 10 and you have Ubuntu inside a VM, and trying to run Windows-only software using Wine?  Wouldn't it make more sense to run Office from Windows?

Comment: I am trying it out, and if office applications work from inside ubuntu, I will be discarding my windows box entirely. However if this does not work, I will have to retain my windows box.

Comment: I re-installed my ubuntu 20.04.01 and went thru the exercise using wine 5.6 in POL. And Yes - now it finally works. Haven't tried to activate my office as yet, but I am a happy puppy!!!! Thank you all so very much. :)